# iOS Handle notifications after starting app from not-running state

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification, uiapplication

I've been trying to handle receiving notifications in my app, but its not really working out.

When I use `didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`. I can receive and use the notification that is used to enter the app, without any problems

However, this function is only fired when the app is already **running** (active, inactive, background, and possibly suspended, but I haven't tried that yet).

Now, there is this function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` where you can use `[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]` which would return a UILocalNotification.

However, when you launch the app from **not-running** state, this event is not fired. The LocalNotification then opens the app, but I can not use it in any way.

Now, my question is: **How can I make it work, so I can receive and process notifications when starting the app, from a notification, when the app is in not-running state?** Is there perhaps something I'm doing wrong here?

Here is a bit of sample code from my app:

First, the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, which, unfortunatly does not work. The function `[sharedLocalNotificationsInstance processNotification:notification]` is never launched...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

LocalNotificationsController *sharedLocalNotificationsInstance = [LocalNotificationsController sharedLocalNotificationsInstance];
[sharedLocalNotificationsInstance checkNotifications];

UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if ( notification != nil ) {

    // Process the received notification
    [sharedLocalNotificationsInstance processNotification:notification];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

return YES;
}
```

And a second piece of code: The didReceiveLocalNotification function, which works perfectly: I receive the notification, and [sharedLocalNotificationsInstance processNotification:notification] works perfectly.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

// Used when the application launches from a notification
LocalNotificationsController *sharedLocalNotificationsInstance = [LocalNotificationsController sharedLocalNotificationsInstance];

// Process the received notification
[sharedLocalNotificationsInstance processNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: Hi laarsk. İ have the same exact problem.
i could catch notifications when app is in foreGround or backGround but funny things happen when app is closed.

i click on notification, app opens, stays on screen for 1 second then screen goes black. i see application in background but no sign of receving notification. I am really not sure whether 

UILocalNotification* notification = (UILocalNotification*)[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

works or not.

Have you found a solid solution for this  ?

Answer (score 4):

This is how iOS handles local notification. It depends on which state of your app, e.g. active, running in background, or not started yet. The iOS will invoke either didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or didReceiveLocalNotification, or won't touch your app at all.

Please see this article for clarification - http://www.thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/62-uilocalnotification-demystified.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunatly, that page also says that the app would launch didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when the app would be in not-running state, which it, unfortunatly, does not... Atleast not as far as I know. Something I'm thinking of right now, is that it might perhaps do something slightly different: launch the app, and then fire the didReceiveLocalNotification event. I only programmed that event to do something when the applicationState = 1 (active), but perhaps I need to use that instead. I'll have a look!

Comment: If your app is not running, when local notification happens and the user activates the notification, iOS will start your app and pass the notification object through the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. However, if the user does not activate the notification, nothing would happen.

Comment: In iOS7, I didn't see any notification from iOS when application is inactive. The badge is set, but when click into icon application, no functions is called.

Comment: Is there way to handle the Local Notifications when the user click on the notification without being in the Delegate? I want catch a deep link from a Local Notification but without do it in Delegate but i don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

`<Matrix-Morpheus-Meme title="WHAT IF I TOLD YOU">`

When an application is launched from the "not-running" state because a user tapped on a local notification alert, the application has been started by iOS, not by Xcode, thus IT IS NOT RUNNING UNDER THE DEBUGGER. You cannot breakpoint inside it and neither does NSLog() send anything to the Xcode console. Test with a `UIAlertController`.

`</Matrix-Morpheus-Meme>`